# Export Access Database to CSV

Tags: ms-access

I want to export an access database to csv format.  When I open up the csv file in excel the dates are messed up.  I have one field with the date. The date fields is fine.  I have another field with just the time.  The time field is messed up.  It shows 12/30/1899 with the correct time.  Can any help me to get only the seconds in the second field.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following expression in the query you are using to create the data:

```
Format(TimeField, "hh:mm:ss AMPM")
```

where TimeField is the name of your field which contains the time.